# Passing a variable value, rather than its name, as a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, twitter-bootstrap, class

I have an array which holds column width class values

```
var colWidth = ["col-sm-0", "col-sm-1", "col-sm-2", "col-sm-3", "col-sm-4", "col-sm-5", "col-sm-6", "col-sm-7", "col-sm-8", "col-sm-9", "col-sm-10", "col-sm-11", "col-sm-12"]
```

A number of other objects may or may not be on the page at any given time, within their own divs. The column width of these divs vary.

I have a function which is run any time anything changes width on the page. It's set up to subtract the widths of everything else on the page from the overall stage width and then apply that value the main div.

```
function widthPlotter() {
    oldStageWidth = stageWidth;
    stageWidth = (12 - (panelWidth + menuWidth));
    newClass = colWidth[stageWidth];
    oldClass = colWidth[oldStageWidth];

    $(activeDiv).toggleClass('oldClass newClass')
}
```

I set up a `toggleClass`, because I want the main column to smoothly animate from its current width to fill the screen when anything else changes.

My issue is this: When that code executes, it literally applies 'oldClass' or 'newClass' to the div, rather than their values (e.g. col-sm-7).

Comment: Side note: Your code, as quoted, is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) because you don't declare your variables.

Comment: Welcome to SO! In general, get right to the problem, don't open with a couple of paragraphs about how you're new to things and have been searching for an answer without finding out. Also: Use stack snippets for **runnable** code; otherwise, just use code formatting. I've edited the question to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it literally applies 'oldClass' or 'newClass' to the div, rather than their values (e.g. col-sm-7).

Of course it does, you've given it a literal string: `'oldClass newClass'`. The quotes make that a string, not references to your variables.

Instead:

```
$(activeDiv).toggleClass(oldClass).toggleClass(newClass);
```

or

```
$(activeDiv).toggleClass(oldClass + " " + newClass);
```

...but the first is probably clearer and just as efficient.

Comment: That fixed it. I'd tried it without the quotes but that broke the page. I knew I was missing something glaringly obvious, but thanks very much for spelling it out for me.